# Creating tabs using Fragments now that TabActivity is deprecated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabactivity, android-tabs

I am creating an application which has five tabs at the bottom of the screen, each of which opens a different Activity.

My Tab Activity extends TabActivity which I have just read is deprecated and I should use Fragments instead.

How do I change my app to use Fragments instead? I have read the information on android.developer.com but I still have no idea how to do this.

Comment: In 2016, use TabLayout from Design Support Library https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need to use the android compatibility library to use fragments. It can be found as a jar file in your android sdk folder.

There are many tutorials out there for fragments.

There is a project named [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) which demos all the capability of the compatibility library. Source code is also available on github. The link is on there site.

This is another tutorial
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/