# How to correctly create a Tablayout now that the Tabactivity is deprecated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabactivity

Since the introduction of Fragments the TabActivity is deprecated.

The Hello Views TabLayout Tutorial however still uses the TabActivity and the API-Documentation has no clear answer on how to create a Tab Layout with Fragments instead of a TabActivity.

How are you building Tablayouts now that the TabActivity is deprecated?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599816/tabactivity-is-deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the release of [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) there is no need to use the old tap API. Just use the new tabs with fragments in any way you like on any recent Android Version (2.x)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had that issue and here is the solution example for that [FragmentTabs.java](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html). But I am still awaiting for the solution that `Fragments` provides instead of using `ActivityGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) or [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) with tabs along with [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) .

I recommend you to use ActionBar with tabs and a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to hold the fragments for each tabs.

in onPageSelected() of [onPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html), set the current tab by getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

and in onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) of [TabListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html) set the current page in viewpager by mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

[Check this example](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) too. Good Luck!