# How to set a new activity with tablayout

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

|In my android application, i have two tabs on all pages. one tab say for activity1 and second for activity2.

let suppose i am at one of my application page, and clicking on a button of this page, i need to call a third activity, which will be displayed on next page which contains two tabs also.
my problem is how to set this third activity, if i set it with tab1, than on clicking on tab1, this third activity shows, means activity1 lost.

Please suggest me some solution for this, its urgent.

Comment: [Use `TabGroupActivity`](http://androidmaterial.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-us-tab-group-activity-in-android.html). but using TabActivity is deprecated. You should use [Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599816/tabactivity-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get you right...
Is this new activity (activity 3) has to be an activity? or it can be just another view?
My point is that you can consider using ViewFlipper/ViewSwitcher and then just change
the views inside the tabs, instead of firing new activity

Comment: No, this third one is an activity not just a view.