# How can I use fragments, now that TabActivity is deprecated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabactivity

I have a main activity with a sort of dock at the bottom, with 4 icons: A, B, C, D.

I already tried getting a response to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868445/how-do-i-replace-a-fragment-in-a-tabhost) involving replacing a fragment within a given tab but did not get an answer. I began to think that maybe I was heading down a wrong path. So now I thought up a new way of implementing it which basically forces me to use the now deprecated TabActivity. The question is, why is it deprecated?

My idea is to implement a system as such :

```
TabActicity(TabActivity)
Tab A(FragmentActivity) -> Fragments
Tab B(FragmentActivity) -> Fragments
Tab C(FragmentActivity) -> Fragments
Tab D(FragmentActivity) -> Fragments
```

Meaning each Tab has its own fragmentActivity that its fragments. Is this the way of implementing the system instead of having a FragmentActivity as my TabController and using fragments as each individual tab ?

Comment: *"[..] did not get an answer.[..]"* - 3 hours are sometimes not enough to get an answer, depending on the question and the people who see it. Be a bit more patient. Also I noticed at lot of code in your linked question. I dídn't read it in detail, but maybe you can cut that down a bit to the relevant details. People will most likely come in, see a wall of code and go "oh no thanks". The faster your question can be parsed, the better *(but don't cut relevant details. Yes, this is a fine line there)*.

Comment: Ive edited out a bit more of the code. Hopefully the message still comes across clearly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a tabs using Fragments now that TabActivity is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599816/creating-a-tabs-using-fragments-now-that-tabactivity-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Android docs you find an example of how to use a TabHost with Fragments. No TabActivity needed.
Here is the example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html

Comment: The link seems to be expired. The sample included with Android sdk support library in <sdk root>/extras/android/support/samples/Support4Demos contains a Fragment Tabs example which helped me.