# Android Fragment Tabs Example

Tags: android-fragments, android

I am currently working on 2.3 version of android and I want to switch my app to 4.0 version but the `TabActivity` is deprecated. So I was looking for working example of `FragmentTabs` but I am not able to find one. Can anyone help?

Comment: A Google search revealed these: http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/ http://neilgoodman.net/2012/03/12/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a tabs using Fragments now that TabActivity is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599816/creating-a-tabs-using-fragments-now-that-tabactivity-is-deprecated)

Comment: The best tutorial: http://neilgoodman.net/2012/03/12/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-2/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found the `FragmentTabs` example from the API Demos project to be very useful.

Just create a new Android sample project from Eclipse and choose the API demos (try API 13). Also for the support (compatibility) library, there's a FragmentTabs demo in the Support4Demos

also refer this link [Android-FragmentTabHost-demo](https://github.com/ClareZhang/Android-FragmentTabHost-demo)

Comment: @Bachi, the source appears to be gone.  See my edit.  It was just a link to the source code.  Just create a new Android sample project from Eclipse and choose the API demos (try API 13).  Also for the support (compatibility) library, there's a `FragmentTabs` demo in the `Support4Demos`.

Answer (score 0):

A great library is ActionBarSherlock. You can find it [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). There are many examples and demos even for fragments.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that Google introduced `ActionBarCompat` in the v7 appcompat library (together with Android 4.3) yesterday. Here's a [video overview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc&feature=c4-overview&list=UUVHFbqXqoYvEWM1Ddxl0QDg), and here's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html).