# Converting TabActivity to Fragment Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented `TabActivity` in my project but as now it is deprecated, so I want to convert that to Tabs that use fragments. Can anyone provide an example which explains converting deprecated `TabActivity` to `Fragments`.

EDIT: I am able to convert `TabActivity` to `FragmentTab`s. But converting activities, that each tab contains, to `Fragment` is a great challenge.. What things do I need to keep in mind while converting `activity` to `Fragment`.

Comment: http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599816/creating-a-tabs-using-fragments-now-that-tabactivity-is-deprecated

Comment: Thanks...It has some helpful information.